# Can/"should" the simple epistemic operator be decomposed into two different operators?

Tags: logic, epistemology, cognition

Typically, in epistemic logic, you have a *k*-operator for, "It is known that..." however often accompanied by a *b*-operator for, "It is believed that..." (and also often enough, these are indexed to specifiable epistemic agents as in, "It is known/believed by So-and-so that..."). However, if knowledge comes in different forms, wouldn't it be more accurate(?) to have multiple elementary *k*-like operators? For example:

1. It is intuitively known (by whomever) that...
2. It is discursively known (by whomever) that...

Now insofar as the concepts of discursion and inference go together, it would seem that (2) has a clear place in epistemic logic, yet it requires (1) to make a difference (or else all knowledge is discursive and there is no reason to emphasize the relevant trait). On the other hand, Kant, for example, seems rather to have understood knowledge as a combination of intuitive and discursive functions. Yet even then, we might say instead that the *k*-operator can be decomposed into, "It is intuitive that..." and, "It is discursive that..." so that *k*S goes to, "It is both intuitive and discursive that..." in the translation limit.

**How many elementary epistemic operators can be assumed before blurring the picture of epistemic logic *as logic* and not as something like mathematics or cognitive science?**

Comment: For agent's epistemic logics with higher-order beliefs like public common and mutual knowledge modelings, the number of elementary operators is bounded up by the number of agents in induction puzzles, for example the famous blue-eyed residents in an island problem. As for intuitive vs discursive understanding Kant and Alvin Goldman would probably say they could be related to various reliable external belief-forming processes which is the justification part of knowledge, thus it's more appropriate to invent Ib and Db operators to stand for "It's intuitively/discursively believed that..."

Comment: Do people that study epistemology really speak in terms of operators? It does seem kind of nebulous to assign pseudo mathematical objects to such fuzzy concepts as "it is believed by Fred."